# colorbox to replace thickbox

Tags: colorbox

I am trying to upgrade thickbox to colorbox.  I think I followed the instructions closely but I still can't make it to work.

My site contains many use class="thickbox".  How do I migrate that to colorbox?
Can someone provide some guidelines?

Please help!  Thank you.
Alan

Answer (score 0):

Did you see the beginner's guide?:
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/guide

Thickbox reads it's optional parameters from the url of your links, while most other jQuery lightboxes (ColorBox included) set their options through javascript.  This may be a little less intuitive, but it allows for less code repetition and stricter separation of concerns.

A ThickBox example:

```
<a href="images/plant1.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="gallery-plants"></a>
<a href="images/plant1.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="gallery-plants"></a>
<a href="images/plant1.jpg" class="thickbox" rel="gallery-plants"></a>
```

The ColorBox equivalent:

```
<a href="images/plant1.jpg" class="thickbox"></a>
<a href="images/plant1.jpg" class="thickbox"></a>
<a href="images/plant1.jpg" class="thickbox"></a>
<script>
    jQuery('.thickbox').colorbox({rel:'gallery-plants'});
</script>
```